# How do I achieve a fixed 'contact details' panel which is revealed by the page scroll up?

Tags: jquery, css

The best way I can explain the effect is by this site's example...

http://www.optimus2020.com/

Any ideas? Its a neat trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the 'panel' has been given `position: fixed;` and placed behind the main content using `z-index`. The scrolling content has a bottom margin/padding equal to the height of the panel. With this technique the browser will scroll 'past' the content, revealing the underlying panel.

Personally I think it's a little strange, but that's just me.

*Code example*

```
<html>
    <head><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>

        <style type="text/css">
            #content {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 10;
                height: 1000px;
                background: #fff;
                margin-bottom: 100px;
            }

            #panel {
                z-index: 1;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100px;
                background: #00f;
                color: #fff;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
            }
        </style>

        <div id="content">Content</div>
        <div id="panel">Panel</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cheers Rob2211, couldn't see the wood for the trees :) I kinda like visual effects like this, just adds something different to a page to catch the users attention.

Comment: Works a treat on our company website [www.crfprinting.co.uk](http://www.crfprinting.co.uk), thanks again!